# Enable transparency in GNOME Activities Overview

Tags: gnome, 13.04, transparency

Instead of having a tranparent background like this:

[image]

...my GNOME Activities Overview is having a solid black background. How can I get the transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems to be a bug of the proprietary `fglrx` driver. Some people recommend turning off the `Have file manager handle the desktop` in the `GNOME Tweak Tool`, but it didn't work for me, so I changed to using the open source ATI driver instead. It's working fine now.

Comment: It happens to me with Intel open-source driver too. So it's not restricted to fglrx.